# Injecting a dynamic html to pages - how to not inherit css?

Tags: html, css

I have this extension which injects HTML as a notification, the problem is that every site renders this HTML different since my HTML code inherits all the css rules.

so I wondered if there's a way to inject this HTML and keep it from rendering different in every website.

Comment: Are they embedded in an iframe? Have you tried that?

Comment: use inline style override in your injected HTML (!important)

Comment: As @kleinfreund pointed out, the iframe is probably your most bulletproof option. There's also a shallow approach with a div containing your HTML and a scoped style tag with a reset.css.

Comment: iframes don't render well in IE 8 for some reason, I've tried that and didn't like the results

Answer (score 0):

I would personally tag up all parts of my html and include inline css rules that specify exactly how I want the html to appear.

Not including any styling information puts you at the mercy of the designers od each site.

Comment: That can easily become a nightmare to maintain. Unless you're targeting email clients, I won't recommend that.

Comment: If you're the one providing html to be rendered, it is your responsibility to style the rendered html, or at the very least, provide class and id tags to allow web-designers to set a style.

Comment: Fair enough. Though the OP's problem seems to be *avoiding* the inherited styles, not adding extra styles.

Comment: True.  Seeing as I cannot comment on questions yet though, I needed to propose something definitive, and could not ask for clarification.